# Which time format to use in a flight booking?

Tags: design-patterns, time, time-zones

I noticed that Virgin America uses a 12-hour time format, while Qatar Airways always uses a 24-hour time format.

**Virgin America:**

[image: Virgin America]

**Qatar Airways:**

[image: Qatar Airways]

1:00AM = 0100H
9:00PM = 2100H
12am = 0000H
12pm = 1200H

Is it okay to use 12MN or 12NN if I choose the 12-hour clock time?

Which time format would be more convenient and understandable for flight bookings?

Comment: localization is really important to show time-zones and time...You should have it according to user preferences.

Comment: But what about the user that is not logged in?

Comment: 12pm is not 2400H, btw.

Comment: @DimitraMiha Cookies can store personalization data, and you can generally get a best guess as to someone's location by using their IP. This doesn't necessarily work for​ someone behind a VPN or proxy, but generally people behind those will be used to odd localization.

Comment: @Kevin I submitted an edit to fix that.

Answer (score 15):

> Times for flights are almost always given as local time in a 24-hour
>   format.

https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83626/how-to-read-time-of-flight-for-emirates-airline

> Most airlines use the 24-hour clock system when telling time. They use
>   this system when assigning trip departures, check-in times and other
>   forms of time designation. The 24-hour clock alleviates communication
>   problems and is more convenient.

http://www.flightattendantcabincrewtraining.com/clock.htm

I think it is interesting to read the following article on times and how people might miss the flight because of time format

https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/travel-on-a-shoestring/topics/anyone-missed-their-flight-due-to-24-hour-clock

This is a very interesting case for further research, but I would suggest going for **24-hour clock**.

What I see is that **this is a convention**. Since most companies use the 24-hour clock, it is better to use the same way, in order to avoid confusion for your passengers.

Answer (score 11):

Make your decision based on your user's location. So, someone in the USA will see AM/PM times and someone in Qatar will see 24H.

Having just one of the two will confuse users of the other region.

**Edit**

More information here: [Date and time representation by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_representation_by_country)

Comment: More information, here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_representation_by_country

Comment: What can you say, example about a user from US (with AM/PM) book a flight going to Qatar, one way. And as going back to US, he/she use the same site in QATAR (with 24H time). There is some inconsistency which become more confusing to the users.

Comment: Give the user an option (for both flights); 'show in AM/PM clock'. That way the user can see one way in 24H and the return flight in AM/PM, or the other way around.

Comment: As someone who sometimes uses a website when on vacation: No! Not based on location. Setting the *default* based on location may be fine, but allow users to set it to a sane setting.

Comment: @Sknny, I think you're confusing **USER** with **PROCESS**. The user is still the same, no matter if she access the site from US or Qatar. System should show time based on user preference and settings (however, the default should be 24 hours time)

Comment: I don't think this is correct. What if I'm an user who uses 24 hours time and access the site from my hotel in US? Will I get something confusing just because I accessed it from another country?

Comment: Default should be 24H, even US citizens get confused. If you add both options, that's great, but I think 24H should be default. No ambiguity there, and no possible confusion.

Comment: @Academiphile Except for people who don't know how to work in 24-hour times (yes, they exist).

Comment: come on @AnthonyGrist , nitpicking much? Even if nobody in US understood 24 hours time (which isn't true at all), that would amount for less than 5% of global population. If 95% uses 24 hours time as default , it's obvious that the default should go to the option used by that 95%, not the option for 5% (which by the way, isn't true!)

Comment: @Devin The global population is irrelevant. A smaller portion of the global population is in the market for airline tickets than of the American population.

Comment: Make it depending on your user's settings, not the location. I expect 24 hours display. That's how my computer and phone are set up. I expect 24 hours display wherever I am, for example in the USA. My settings are also "English". I'd be very, very annoyed if you displayed in Chinese just because I went to China,

Answer (score 8):

People who are used to the am/pm format will be able to correctly understand the 24:00 format. People who are used to the 24:00 format will occasionally **misunderstand** 12:00 pm. Even people who are used to am/pm will occasionally [misunderstand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight) 12:00 pm.

So if context doesn't clarify if we're talking midnight or noon, and it's important to avoid misunderstandings, use 24:00. Same if you expect a lot of international users. International long distance flights satisfy all of these these criteria. US inland flights don't.

- For international long distance flights, use 24:00.
- For US domestic flights, both options are viable.
- If your site displays both intercontinental and domestic US flights, use 24:00 to maintain consistency.
- Ideally you provide an option that allows the user to easily show the second format.

Comment: +1 . For most people who use 2400 time , 12AM and 12PM are really confusing, you have to think twice which one is 00:00 and which one is 24:00, and even them people confuses them anyways. That's why armies use the 2400 format (and therefore is known as Military Time, see http://militarytimechart.com/) : because it is the best way to avoid confusion. Furthermore, it's not only the method used by military, but also for any activity that requires precision and needs to get rid of any ambiguity.

Comment: Ironically, the list of people who misunderstand 12:00pm includes the OP... :-)

Comment: Note that 24:00 on May 1 is the same as 0:00 on May 2, though I would suggest such a time should only be used to describe something that begins earlier on the same day and ends at midnight (e.g. describing something as running from 18:00-24:00 on May 1 makes it visually clear that the interval in question is six hours).

Comment: Don't airlines generally use 23:59 or 11:59pm rather than 24:00?

Comment: It is not true that people who are used to the am/pm format will correctly understand the 24:00 format. To a person used to the am/pm format, a time like 07:00 is ambiguous and may be misunderstood.

Comment: @AlexanderDunlap, someone used to AM/PM seeing "07:00" will be prompted to ask "Is that AM or PM?".  Someone used to 24-hour time seeing "7:00 PM" will initially think "07:00".  Which situation do you think has less potential for mistakes?

Comment: @Mark I am used to AM/PM times and if I already have a sense (correct or incorrect) that the time should be "in the morning" or "in the evening" I am prone to make the wrong assumption.

Comment: Even US domestic flights have a lot of international passengers. A single solution is advisable.

Comment: @supercat's advice agrees with ISO 8601.

Comment: @FabioTurati According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight) I think you cannot say "misunderstand".

Comment: 12:00am and 12:00pm are both wrong - correct is "midnight" and "noon". Alternatively, change the time to 12:01, @AndrewM.Farrell: Yes, airlines won't have flights leaving at 12:00.